# IBM MobileFirst and SQL Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server

I have a MS-SQL server and I want to connect IBM SQL Adapter to get data from one table. Does IBM MFPF support MS-SQL server connectivity ?

can anyone share their experience how to connect with MS-SQL Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MobileFirst provides supports for MS-SQL server connectivity.

There are three approaches you can take:

1) Use [Java SQL Adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/java-sql-adapter/).
2) Use [Javascript SQL Adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/js-sql-adapter/).
3) Use [Java adapters](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/java-http-adapter/).

For 1) and 2) the DB connection details are specified in the adapter.xml directly. Alternatively you can define a datasource in the application server and refer that in the adapter.xml

Option 3) involves the use of Java adapters and the developer filling in Java code that connects to and performs CRUD operations on MS-SQL.

Comment: Thanks Guys ! I hope I can get image data through any of these adapter and display on my application(Hybrid MFPF 7.1)